# Причина несовместимости типов

Tags: java, компиляция

Я написал следующую hadoop программу

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class ParallelIndexation {
    //public static native long Traveser(String Path);

    //public static native void Configure(String Path);

    //static {
    //  System.loadLibrary("nativelib");
    //}
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        private final static LongWritable zero = new LongWritable(0);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            Path localPath = new Path("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt");
            Path hdfsPath=new Path("hdfs://user/hadoop/paths.txt");
            Path localPath1 = new Path("/usr/countcomputers.txt");                
            Path hdfsPath1=new Path("hdfs://user/hadoop/countcomputers.txt");
            if (!fs.exists(hdfsPath))
            {
                fs.copyFromLocalFile(localPath, hdfsPath);
            };
            if (!fs.exists(hdfsPath1))
            {
                fs.copyFromLocalFile(localPath1, hdfsPath1);
            };          
            FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(hdfsPath);
            String line = in.read();
            // String line = value.toString();
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(hdfsPath1)));
            int CountComputers;
            /* FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
                    "/usr/countcomputers.txt");
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); */
            String result=br.readLine();
            CountComputers=Integer.parseInt(result);
            in.close();
            // fstream.close();
            ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                paths.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }
            String[] ConcatPaths = new String[CountComputers];
            int NumberOfElementConcatPaths = 0;
            if (paths.size() % CountComputers == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < CountComputers; i++) {
                    ConcatPaths[i] = paths.get(NumberOfElementConcatPaths);
                    NumberOfElementConcatPaths += paths.size() / CountComputers;
                    for (int j = 1; j < paths.size() / CountComputers; j++) {
                        ConcatPaths[i] += "\n"
                                + paths.get(i * paths.size() / CountComputers
                                        + j);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                NumberOfElementConcatPaths = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < paths.size() % CountComputers; i++) {
                    ConcatPaths[i] = paths.get(NumberOfElementConcatPaths);
                    NumberOfElementConcatPaths += paths.size() / CountComputers
                            + 1;
                    for (int j = 1; j < paths.size() / CountComputers + 1; j++) {
                        ConcatPaths[i] += "\n"
                                + paths.get(i
                                        * (paths.size() / CountComputers + 1)
                                        + j);
                    }
                }
                for (int k = paths.size() % CountComputers; k < CountComputers; k++) {
                    ConcatPaths[k] = paths.get(NumberOfElementConcatPaths);
                    NumberOfElementConcatPaths += paths.size() / CountComputers;
                    for (int j = 1; j < paths.size() / CountComputers; j++) {
                        ConcatPaths[k] += "\n"
                                + paths.get((k - paths.size() % CountComputers)
                                        * paths.size() / CountComputers
                                        + paths.size() % CountComputers
                                        * (paths.size() / CountComputers + 1)
                                        + j);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < ConcatPaths.length; i++) {
                word.set(ConcatPaths[i]);
                output.collect(word, zero);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
            Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        public native long Traveser(String Path);

        public native void Configure(String Path);

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<LongWritable> value,
                OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            long count=0;
            String line = key.toString();
            ArrayList<String> ProcessedPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                ProcessedPaths.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }
            Configure("/etc/nsindexer.conf");
            for (int i = 0; i < ProcessedPaths.size(); i++) {
                count = Traveser(ProcessedPaths.get(i));
            }
            output.collect(key, new LongWritable(count));
        }

        static {
            System.loadLibrary("nativelib");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(ParallelIndexation.class);
        conf.setJobName("parallelindexation");
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

В результате компиляции с помощью команды

```
    root@one:/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/bin# ./javac -classpath /export/hadoop-1.0.1/hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar -d /folder/classes /folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java
```

я получил следующую ошибку

```
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:42: error: incompatible types
            String line = in.read();
                                 ^
  required: String
  found:    int
1 error
```

Помогите устранить ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам компилятор сообщает, что требуется String, а возвращается int. Строки можно читать с помощью метода readLine.

Comment: @a_gura я сделал как вы сказали, использовав readLine (так как файл состоит из одной строки) и получил в результате компиляции

 /folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:42: warning: [deprecation] readLine() in DataInputStream has been deprecated
    String line = in.readLine();
        ^
 1 warning

Comment: Еще раз, читайте сообщения компилятора. Как правило, эти сообщения содержат исчерпывающую информацию. В данном случае, компилятор выдал вам предупреждение, которое говорит о том, что метод readLine класса DataInputStream устарел.

Вы можете проигнорировать это предупреждение на свой страх и риск, а можете почитать документацию к используемым классам и найти альтернативное решение.

Негоже по каждой мелочи писать на форум. Научитесь работать с документацией.

Comment: @a_gura, научиться работать с документацией порой самое сложное в изучении языка.